# using oracle 11g, how can i resolve 502 bad gateway error in nginx web server?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I found this bad gateway error on almost regular bases, after restart server machine it got resolved.
In my oracle apex application number of end users upto 10k and having 200 plus forms and reports. 
I want to find the reason behind this bad gateway server error.
is there any way for tuning my oracle schema ?

i am using oracle 11g and oracle apex 19.1

my server machine configuratoin is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQsYN.png)

my oracle schema's current sessions,processes,transactions values are 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB4Oj.png)

and the error we found 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlc4J.png)

Answer (score 0):

A 502 error can be caused by many things, almost none of which have to do directly with your Oracle schema. See here for troubleshooting tips: https://www.howtogeek.com/356389/what-is-a-502-bad-gateway-error-and-how-can-i-fix-it/

In a nutshell, since it works for a while and works again after a reboot, it is most likely a system resource issue of some kind. Another thing to consider is whether the error happens in relation to any *specific* user activity like running a particular report. I would be monitoring OS performance and resources on all of the servers involved, as well as the APEX workspace logs for application errors or the Oracle AWR reports and alert log for any issue with DB resources.

If it is a resource issue then you may have to look at adding more CPU or memory (or whatever appears to be lacking) to your configuration, or look at potentially modifying your custom SQL and PL/SQL code to be more efficient.